# Does the sum of reciprocals of this subset of the primes converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, prime-numbers

Here

[On the distribution of "nice" primes (primes $p$ , such that $\pi(p)$ is prime as well)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874954/on-the-distribution-of-nice-primes-primes-p-such-that-pip-is-prime-a)

"nice" primes (primes $p$, such that $\pi(p)$ is prime as well) are introduced.

> Is it known whether the sum of the reciprocals of the nice primes is convergent ?

The sum of the reciprocals of the primes in an arithmetic progression $an+b$ , where $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $n$ runs over the natural numbers, is divergent.

Intuitively, I would expect that there should exist enough nice primes to get a divergent series, but I may be wrong.

Has anyone an idea or a reference ?

Comment: Another thing I am interested in : What is the largest known "nice" prime ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), ultimately we have
$$.9\,n\,\log n \leq p_n \leq 1.1 \,n\,\log n$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.

The $n$th nice prime is $p_{p_n}$, so we ultimately get
$$p_{p_n} \geq .9\,p_n\,\log(p_n)\geq .9 \,(.9\,n\,\log n)\,\log(.9\,n\,\log n).$$

Since that last logarithm is equivalent to $\log n$, we ultimately get 
$$p_{p_n} \geq .5\,n\,(\log n)^2$$
so
$$\frac 1{p_{p_n}} \leq \frac{2}{n\,(\log n)^2} \qquad\text{ultimately,}$$
which proves that $\sum_n \frac{1}{p_{p_n}}$ converges, because $\sum \frac 1{n(\log n)^\alpha}$ converges iff $\alpha > 1$ (that's a Bertrand series, it's for example an application of [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) or of an integral comparison).